# What are play frameworks default cache settings?

Tags: scala, playframework

In play 2.3.x, when i use http caching like this, what are the default cache settings? How much memory will be used? How many objects will be stored? Will the cache also be persisted to disk? How long will entries be kept before they are refreshed? Where can i find this information?

```
def index = Cached("homePage") {
  Action {
    Ok("Hello world")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EHcache is the default implementation to the CacheApi interface in play.
You can read about it here:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaCache

And if this is not enough you can checkout the module that is being loaded:

```
play.api.cache.EhCacheModule
```

And check for the properties that are being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the details can be found here, thanks for pointing me in the right direction, Tomer:
https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/2.3.x/framework/src/play-cache/src/main/resources/ehcache-default.xml

How much memory will be used?
Undefined

How many objects will be stored? 
10000 objects will be cached.

Will the cache also be persisted to disk?
no

How long will entries be kept before they are refreshed?
120 seconds